how to search a text within a text from a field in DB2
I have the following data in a table as below,



Column1
Column2




ABC
pat.getString("IMAGE") =="Y"):pat.setValue("CONDITIONCODE","");


XYZ
pat.getString("IMAGE")=="N"): pat.setValue("CONDITIONCODE,"REPAIR")


PRS
pat.getString("REFRESH")



I need to write a SQL query to fetch the list of records that has "" within the setValue. In the above example the query should return the first row only.

Not Sure this is the best solution, but it works. Lets say table_3 is your table name. You can use the below query to achieve the results.
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM (
    SELECT  

    CASE 
        WHEN PATINDEX('%pat.setValue(%', column2) > 0 
        THEN PATINDEX('%pat.setValue(%', column2) + 12 
        ELSE 0 
    END as StartIndex, *
    FROM TABLE_3

    ) AS A
WHERE StartIndex > 0
 AND PATINDEX('%""%', SUBSTRING(column2, STARTINDEX, LEN(column2)-StartIndex ))>0

Hope this helps!

To fetch records from a table where the setValue method contains an empty string (""), you can use SQL's LIKE operator in your query
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name
WHERE Column2 LIKE setValue("",'%');


This will return none of the rows OP showed, but they want to get the first.
